# C# Use of unassigned local variable (2 different loops, int)

Tags: c#

I get the same error message all the time and i can't figure out where to put my int victimCount to make it work not just inside the while loop but to use it for my for loop as well. Suggestions?

```
namespace FibonacciSequence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            int i;
            int victimCount;
            double f1 = 0;
            double f2 = 1;
            double f3 = 0;

            bool running = true;

            while (running)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the number of victims so we can predict the next murder, Sherlock: ");
                victimCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (victimCount == 1)
                {
                    Console.Write("that's an invalid number.");
                }
                else
                {
                    running = false;
                }
            }                 
            for (i = 0; i <= victimCount; i++)
            {
                f3 = f1 + f2;
                f1 = f2;
                f2 = f3;
                Console.WriteLine("Victim " + f1);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }         
}
```

Comment: thanks for all the answers, rookie problem solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't figure out where to put my int victimCount to make it work not just inside the while loop but to use it for my for loop as well

The variable is placed correctly. Compiler complains that in can stay unassigned here

```
for (i = 0; i <= victimCount; i++)
```

because it thinks that `while` loop may never run.

```
int victimCount = 0;
```

should fix the compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

you need to assign the variable. It's not a matter of where you declare it. The compiler can'ts see that it will always be assigned before the for loop.

if you change your declaration to

```
int victimCount = 0;
```

you will no longer get the compile error and if you for some reason do not assign it the for loop will not iterate.

in reality the compiler would be able to spot that your code does indeed assign the variable a value but resolving that in a more general manner the compiler might have to solve an NP-Complete problem which might take forever (literally) which of course would be a bad thing so the compiler do not try to be that smart about the detection.

You could skip your running variable all together and simply use victimCount. at the same time you should probably change your test of what's parsed from the console

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var victimCount=0;
        var f1 = 0.0;
        var f2 = 1.0;
        var f3 = 0.0;

        while (victimCount<2)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the number of victims so we can predict the next murder, Sherlock: ");
            //see if you can parse it and that the number is larger than 1
            //that's assuming that not only 1 is invalid 
            //but also 0 and negative numbers
            //using tryparse ensures that even if the user types letters
            //your program won't crash
            if(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out victimCount) || victimCount < 2){
                Console.Write("that's an invalid number.");
            }
        }                 
        for (var i = 0; i <= victimCount; i++)
        {
            f3 = f1 + f2;
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = f3;
            Console.WriteLine("Victim " + f1);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just assign an initial value to your variable:

```
int victimCount = 0;
```

The error you get is due to the fact that the compiler doesn't know if the statements in your `while` will be executed. Hence, compiler assumes that variable `victimCount` may not be assigned a value. If so, then you can't use it to your `for` statement. In order to avoid this, you could use the initial assignemt, I reffered to above.

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the variable:

```
int victimCount = 0;
```

for example.

Also, it's good practice to declare the variables close to where you need to use them, e.g. in  your `for` loop, you can declare i there...

```
for (var i = 0; i <= victimCount; i++)
```

so, you can remove `int i;` from the group above.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is in the correct place. However, as the error message says, your `for` loop is reading a variable that may not have been assigned yet.

The compiler can't prove that the `while` loop will run at least once (even though it will), so it can't prove that `victimCount` will have a value by the time it reaches the `for` loop.

So, assign a default value to `victimCount` when you declare it.

```
int victimCount = 0;
```

An alternative would be to help the compiler prove that the `while` loop will run at least once, by using `while(true)` and `break`:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the number of victims so we can predict the next murder, Sherlock: ");
    victimCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (victimCount == 1)
        Console.Write("that's an invalid number.");
    else
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign it a default value:

```
int victimCount = 0;
```

The compiler is simply warning you that it's unassigned because you only assign it within the first loop, and the compiler can't *guarantee* that the first loop will execute at runtime.  (It knows that the runtime value of the loop condition *might* result in 0 iterations.)